# datagridview disable automatic parsing

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, datagridview

My project has a DataGridView that the user can edit and save to a DB.  I am trying to add validation to the DataGridView.  (Certain columns are required, and can only be numbers (specifically, doubles)).

I am having trouble working around some automated parsing done by .Net behind the scenes.  The behavior of the DataGridView is different depending on whether the user leaves a required field blank or enters something that cannot be parsed as a double (i.e., text).

Easier Case : if the user leaves a required field blank and clicks Save.  The Save button's click event fires, and I am able to check that the cell's Value property is set to `DBNull`, in which case I set the cell's `ErrorText` property and show a `MessageBox`.

Harder Case : When the user enters text that cannot be parsed as a double (e.g., "asdf").  When this happens, as soon as the cell loses focus, some built-in .Net validation occurs behind the scenes, and I get a message box showing a stack trace.  I want to disable this validation completely and just do my own validation when the user clicks Save.

(Up until that point, the invalid data doesn't matter).  Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can cancel validation using the code below - although I've not tested it I believe setting the DataGridViews `CausesValidation` property to false might have the same effect.

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellValidating(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellValidating
    e.Cancel = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Neither of those options worked.  Setting CausesValidation = false seemed to have no affect, and using the CellValidating handler you suggested caused an error messagebox on form_load (when the grid is populated), because cancelling the event means it failed to commit a cell value.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my problem by editing my sql query to convert the floats to nvarchars.  Now the DataGridView thinks the datatype is text, which it can't validate by any kind of default logic.  I also found that the value is not committed unless the user hits enter, so my validation code checks against the cell's EditedFormattedValue property instead of Value.